# Bash script: perform actions based on file contents

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I have a bash script that loops through all folders inside a given path and performs some actions.

I now need this script to find the given path by itself, by monitoring a file that I will update from my server.

So, the script has to:

1. check if file todo.txt exists
2. read the first line of the file
3. perform actions inside the folder defined in that first line
4. delete todo.txt
5. append done.txt with the same line it found in todo.txt

For some reason, when I run the script directly, this works perfect

```
cd /proper/path/to/todo
FILE=todo.txt
if [ -f $FILE ];
then
    FOLDER=$(head -1 $FILE)
    echo "path to process:"$FOLDER
fi;
```

The output is good, the file is read, the output is "path to process: /correct/path/read/from/file"

However, when I set up a cron job to run this script, the $FOLDER variable is empty so the output is just "path to process:"

```
* * * * * /bin/sh /www/www.mysite.com/myscript.sh >> /www/www.mysite.com/log.txt
```

Note that:
1. the script IS ran
2. the if [ -f $FILE ] works, so the file is found

It's just the head command that fails.

Any ideas? thanks!

Comment: `$PATH` isn't set by cron.  Your script can't get `head`.

Comment: If you append you cronjob command line with 2>&1 , you can log error message

Comment: @eduffy, I am setting PATH in my crontab file like this:
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/bin:/usr/games:/opt/gnome/bin:/usr/lib/mit/bin:/usr/lib/mit/sbin:/usr/local/RealPlayer:/opt/dell/srvadmin/bin:

Comment: How about the $FILE content, maybe it just an empty file

Comment: Unfortunately, echo $FILE shows the correct name and path in both cases (when I run directly and from cron)

Comment: and the contents are not empty, I triple-quadrupled checked :)

Comment: what happens if you replace `FOLDER=$(head -1 $FILE)` with `read FOLDER < "$FILE"` ?

Comment: add `set -eu` to the top of the file and schedule `/bin/bash -x script.sh`

Comment: @thom that works!! But now the next line fails: for i in $(ls) . Is there a specific set of functions I am allowed to use when running the script from a cron job?

Comment: the `$( )` syntax starts a new shell.  You may have to export `PATH`, not just set it.

Comment: Yes indeed, I just wanted to know if `read` would work instead of `head` because `read` is an internal command and for `head` you need a functional `$PATH`. So @eduffy has probably just given the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like `/usr/bin` is not in cron's PATH. Try this: add this entry into cron

```
* * * * * env > $HOME/cron.env
```

Wait a minute and see what that file says.

---

[Don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) -- instead of `for i in $(ls)` do `for file in *`. Since `for` iterates over **words**, any filename with whitespace will not be handled properly