# Bash script to read a file and run a command based on a specific string

Tags: linux, bash

I am needing a bash script which, when a file is saved to a particular directory (file name could be anything), read its contents and then, if a particular string in the file is found then run a specific command/or another script.

I have had a look through [Bash script: perform actions based on file contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20273733/bash-script-perform-actions-based-on-file-contents) but this script appears to depend on the file being named. My bash scripting is next to useless so hoping someone can help :)

Comment: try writing something and we can give you feedback then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you install the `inotify-tools` package, you can use `inotifywait` for this:

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR_TO_WATCH=/tmp
STRING=foobar

cd "$DIR_TO_WATCH"

inotifywait -qme close_write --format '%f' -r ./ | while read changed_file; do
  if grep "$STRING" "$changed_file" &>/dev/null; then
    echo "$STRING found on file $changed_file!"
  fi
done
```

I recommend you take a look at [`inotifywait`s manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait) for more details on the command-line options

Comment: This great. I am modifying it a little to include several matches, run a script.